# Incompatible Types - found:int required:boolean

Tags: java

I'm trying to display: EQUIVALENT if the first numerical input is equal to the second input. What's wrong with my code?

```
import java.io.*;
public class TwoNum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number;
        int number2;
        String input1="";
        String input2="";

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Input a number: ");

        try{
            input1=in.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

        number = Integer.parseInt(input1);

        try{
            input2=in.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }

        number2 = Integer.parseInt(input2);

        if(number=number2)
        {
            System.out.println("EQUIVALENT");
        }
        if(number>number2)
        {
            System.out.println("GREATER THAN");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the Java compiler should have complained about the if(number=number2). Did you happen to see some compilation error message?

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
 if(number==number2)
```

Instead of

```
 if(number=number2)
```

The first compares `number2` to `number` and if they are equal evaluates to `true`.  The second *assigns* the value of `number2` to the variable `number` and the expression evaluates to number/number2, an int.

### Link

- [Summary of Operators (The Java Tutorials)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `number=number2` is an assignment expression producing an integer.  But a boolean is expected in this context.  You want `==` instead of `=`.  Common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition should be:

```
if(number==number2)
```

In if condition use `==` to compare 2 integers. Also don't use if in both condition use `else if()`. Using `if` in both will check condition for both even though first condition is true it will check for second condition and you are missing 3rd condition for `LESS THAN`.